# Uninstalling Vista from dual boot of Windows 7/Vista

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, multi-boot

Topic title says it all. Right now I have 2 things I need to do...

1) Remove the Windows.old folder.

My problem with this is that when I go to disk cleanup, the "Remove Previous Window Installations" option isn't there. Not sure what to do here.

EDIT: Solved this part. Didn't hit button clean up system files, was just looking at normal disk cleanup window.

2) The rest..

I've read that I should use EasyBCD, but I'm not sure what to do with it once I get it. Any help is appreciated.  .

EDIT: I downloaded EasyBCD, and I see the option to add/delete entries. Do I just need to delete the Vista entry, or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 2):

EasyBCD will just help you to remove the Vista entry from the boot menu.  In EasyBCD select the "Add/Remove Entries"  button and delete the Vista entry.

Comment: After removing the windows.old folder and removing the vista entry from the boot menu, am I set or is there more to it? ( As in, is Vista completely "off" my computer ).

Comment: Did you dual-boot or do an upgrade?  I don't know why you would have a Windows.old folder if you were dual-booting, that typcially gets created from doing an in-place upgrade.  When dual-booting you should just have to remove the Vista partition and make sure your boot menu is correct.  Also, I would suggest exporting yor BCD configuration before changing anything, just in case.

Comment: Well I used an ISO to install Vista, and that didn't provide the option for a clean install (which is what I wanted, but the ISO was my only option.) When it asked where to put Windows7, I chose the drive that currently held Windows Vista. The setup said that it would be bringing over old files.

Comment: Basically, I guess I installed Windows7 "over" the current partition used for Vista, but I still have the option to dual boot to Vista, though I haven't even tried it yet.

Comment: I would suspect that if you tried to boot into Vista it either wouldn't work or would just boot your Windows 7.  Removing Windows.old and the Vista boot entry should remove any remains of Vista.